# Delphi TParallel.For slower than classic for

Tags: delphi, asynchronous

I need to populate a `TJsonArray` with a lot of `TJsonObject` (`TJsonArray` and `TJsonObject` are from [JsonDataObjects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects)). I'm trying `TParallel.For()` from the `System.Threading` unit to improve performance, but my `TParallel.For()` is slower than a classic `for` loop.

This is my testing code:

```
var
  aLock:  TCriticalSection;
  jItems: TJsonArray;
  jItem:  TJsonObject;
  aStart: Cardinal;
  aEnd:   Cardinal;
  i:      integer;
begin
  // array of json objects
  jItems  := TJsonArray.Create;

  // ASYNC FOR LOOP
  // ----------------------------
  aLock  := TCriticalSection.Create;
  aStart := GetTickCount;
  TParallel.&For(0, 10000000,
    procedure(k: Integer)
    var
      xItem: TJsonObject;
    begin
      aLock.Enter;
      try
        // add new object to the array
        xItem := jItems.AddObject;
      finally
        aLock.Leave;
      end;
      // populate some object property for test
      xItem.I['I'] := k; // .I for integer
      xItem.F['F'] := k; // .F for float
      xItem.S['S'] := IntToStr(k); // .S for string
      xItem.D['D'] := Now; // .D for date
    end
  );
  aEnd := GetTickCount;
  Writeln('ASYNC ', aEnd-aStart);
  // ----------------------------

  aLock.Free;
  jItems.Clear;

  // SYNC FOR LOOP
  // ----------------------------
  aStart := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 10000000 do begin
    jItem := jItems.AddObject;
    jItem.I['I'] := i;
    jItem.F['F'] := i;
    jItem.S['S'] := IntToStr(i);
    jItem.D['D'] := Now;
  end;
  aEnd := GetTickCount;
  Writeln('SYNC ', aEnd-aStart);
  // ----------------------------

  jItems.Free;
end;
```

This is the result (the numbers are the times elapsed in millisecond):

[image]

I think my `TParallel.For()` implementation is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've made the mistake of thinking that multi-threading automatically makes things faster, which it does not. It often makes things slower, as you have context switches and locking operations that take time. *Multi-threaded* doesn't mean *magically faster*.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, just a my mistake or there is something wrong into my code, like work on shared variable jItems?

Comment: I'd bet the critical section is your bottleneck. It also makes your asynchronous code work almost the same as the synchronous one. When you sum it up, you get that 4541 milliseconds is the cost for locking and context switching.

Comment: I didn't say your code had a mistake. I said you're making a mistake when thinking that multi-threading magically means *faster*. Your standard for loop is considerably faster because it does much less than the parallel version. Start with it not having to lock and unlock on every operation, and having considerably less overhead than `TParallel.For`

Comment: @PeterWolf yes, i have tried to remove it and the async code become faster...

Comment: @KenWhite without lock this code is broken as lock prevents concurrent adding items to list. For this code as-is using parallel for is just wrong tool.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: I did not suggest removing the lock. I merely pointed out that using it also had an impact on the speed comparison.  Why is no one reading the actual words I'm writing here? :-) *Using threads does not magically make code faster, because there is additional overhead using the threads that the straight `for` loop does not have, including the locking operations.*  Note *threads not magically faster** and **additional overhead including locking*, neither of which suggests *you should remove the locks* or *there's something wrong with the code*..

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I was reading to fast... and I somehow merged your comment with OP's comment where he said that after removing the lock his async code was running faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your use of a critical section around the `TJsonArray` serializes your threads and is likely a major bottleneck.  Try getting rid of the critical section, preallocate the array before entering the loop, and then have each loop iteration simply fill in an existing slot of the array as needed.  This way, you have a better chance of inserting multiple objects into the array at the same time in parallel.

```pascal
var
  jItems: TJsonArray;
  jItem:  TJsonObject;
  aStart: Cardinal;
  aEnd:   Cardinal;
  i:      integer;
begin
  // array of json objects
  jItems  := TJsonArray.Create;

  // ASYNC FOR LOOP
  // ----------------------------
  jItems.Count := 10000001; // <-- add this!
  aStart := GetTickCount;
  TParallel.&For(0, 10000000,
    procedure(k: Integer)
    var
      xItem: TJsonObject;
    begin

      // create new object
      xItem := TJsonObject.Create;

      // populate some object property for test
      xItem.I['I'] := k; // .I for integer
      xItem.F['F'] := k; // .F for float
      xItem.S['S'] := IntToStr(k); // .S for string
      xItem.D['D'] := Now; // .D for date

      // add new object to the array
      jItems.O[k] := xItem;
    end
  );
  aEnd := GetTickCount;
  Writeln('ASYNC ', aEnd-aStart);
  // ----------------------------

  jItems.Clear;

  // SYNC FOR LOOP
  // ----------------------------
  aStart := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 10000000 do begin
    jItem := jItems.AddObject;
    jItem.I['I'] := i;
    jItem.F['F'] := i;
    jItem.S['S'] := IntToStr(i);
    jItem.D['D'] := Now;
  end;
  aEnd := GetTickCount;
  Writeln('SYNC ', aEnd-aStart);
  // ----------------------------

  jItems.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing functionally wrong with your code, this is simply the wrong problem to use multithreading to accelerate.  The major bottlenecks here are simply heap allocations for creating the `TJSONObject`s, so even if you didn't add the overhead of threading and locks you would still be in contention for the memory manager which will serialize all of those allocations anyway.

At this point, if performance is a problem, it's probably time to consider a different architecture altogether.  You could try to force this multithreading idea with a custom multithreaded memory manager, but really the efforts are probably not worth it.  JSON is not optimal for large datasets.  If you need to encode and transmit 10 million records quickly, another technology is probably the correct answer.